# Allow users from external network to access SSAS cubes

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, powerbi, cubes

I would like to know what are the ways in which the following can be achieved.

Suppose a company named CompanyA is using SSAS cubes and CompanyA is acquired by another company named CompanyB. The users of  CompanyA are migrated to CompanyB network in a phased manner.

Hence the SSAS cubes should be accessible to users who still reside in CompanyA network and also to users who have been migrated to CompanyB network.

Also the CompanyA domain does not belong to the trusted user domain of CompanyB 
and vice versa

Is such a scenario feasible to achieve. If yes then please let me know what are the ways to achieve this other than using VPN.

I have googled for this scenario, but most of them talk about a external network. But this case the external network belongs to a acquired company which makes it a different case.

Comment: Is Azure Analysis Services and Tabular models an option? It makes this scenario easy.

Comment: @GregGalloway: Thank you. We are not using Azure. We are hosting them on Windows server 2008 R2

Comment: For what it is worth if I was working with you I would push back on that decision hard. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: What client tools are in scope? Power BI? Excel? Custom website?

Comment: Will your AD domain trust the AD domain of the acquired company? One way or two way or no trust?

Comment: @GregGalloway: There is no trust between the two domains. The client tools in scope are SSRS reports, Excel, Power BI. Since this is a relatively new client we cannot suggest them changes to the architecture. Maybe at a later stage we will push this idea to them

Comment: Since this is a relatively new client we cannot make changes to the architecture. Maybe at a later stage we will suggest the idea of using Azure Analysis services.

Comment: is there any role based security so that one user sees different data (like the northwest region only) than other people?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest option (least code and least sophistication) is to daily backup the cubes, copy the backup files to a new SSAS server on the Company B network, then restore the backups skipping the members of security roles (which is an option in the restore dialog in SSMS). All this could be automated to run daily. Maybe the new Company B domain server could even have a DNS alias matching the name of the server on the Company A network.

However if you want to not host another copy of the cube in the Company B domain then there is another option that would require some C# coding. For Excel users you can host this [proxy code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SSASProxy-Custom-HTTP-7db6d016/) in a publically accessible website. The website allows "basic auth" and the code is responsible for saying whether the credentials are valid or not. So you could figure out how to let Company B users authenticate appropriately. Make sure to use HTTPS. This solution uses the CustomData property to pass the username to the cube. So you would need to setup a custom role in the cube using the [CustomData() MDX function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491991/cube-level-security-using-customdata) or ignore that if no data level security is needed. I have done this for a client so it definitely works.

For SSRS I would recommend setting up a separate custom website for Company B users which displays the appropriate reports using the [ReportViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control?) control in Remote processing mode. This assumes reports could connect to SSAS with a Company A service account and all users see the same data.

I would recommend the above SSRS approach as it is easier and less invasive than changing the whole SSRS website over to use [custom forms auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-custom-or-forms-authentication-on-the-report-server?).

For Power BI, you can have the gateway change to use CustomData. In the Power BI website to the gear icon... Manage gateways... Expand the gateway and data source... click the Users tab... click the Map user names button. You will see a screen like this. Choose CustomData.

[image: Map user names dialog]

I believe you should just be able to invite bob@companyb.com users and it should work. I suspect the dashboard must either be running on Power BI Premium in the Company A Power BI tenant or bob@companyb.com must have a Power BI Pro license.

Incidentally, Power BI Desktop and Power BI Service last I checked did not support the custom SSAS proxy I mentioned for the Excel scenario above. But if you can publish to the Power BI service using the Map user names CustomData setting mentioned above you shouldn't need users to connect in Power BI Desktop.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the suggestions that you have mentioned. How about http access to the ssas cubes. Will this method allow external users to access the ssas cubes and allow the use of AD groups to grant access to specific cubes

Comment: @bharathy regular HTTP access (through msmdpump) would require all users to authenticate with a Company A domain user account. The proxy code mentioned above can be any authentication. Yes. If you write the C# code to validate Company B auth then it can do it. And you can setup dynamic security with the CustomData function to grant access to only the appropriate data for that Company B user.

Comment: Thank you.Hi Greg does the above hold good even if there is no trust between Company A and company B

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share any links if you have regarding "C# code to validate Company B auth then it can do it. And you can setup dynamic security with the CustomData function to grant access to only the appropriate data for that Company B user".

Comment: I don't have any links on that. You would have to figure out how to verify auth is correct given your particular network and AD setup

Comment: Thank you. I went through the SSASProxy Custom HTTP Security sample. I am bit confused about how the  publically accessible website knows the users who try to login to the website are users from Company B. Where does it store username and passwords of the users from Company B. How does it restrict users who are not from Company B from logging in to the website

Comment: @raki.dbit that's up to you to write. If it were just plain vanilla windows auth then there would be no need of this proxy. Basically you grab the username and password they authenticate with and validate it against the appropriate domain or whatever you choose.